# Refusal of entry into US by CBP for last few days of validity of US visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration

If my US visa is valid till March 15th 2019, then can I enter into US on 13th Mar 2019? Can CBP (Customs & Border Protection) at the US port of arrival refuse entry based on validity of visa?

Answer (score 3):

They can refuse you but your visa is valid and if you're a genuine visitor you should be fine. You will tell tho CBP officer how long you're staying and they will give you a stamp with the last day you're allowed to leave. If you stay over the date they give you you'll be an overstayer.

> The visa expiration date is shown on the visa along with the visa
> issuance date. The time between visa issuance and expiration date is
> called your visa validity. The visa validity is the length of time you
> are permitted to travel to a port-of-entry in the United States.
>
> Upon arriving at a port of entry, the CBP official will determine the
> length of your visit.
>
> The admitted-until date or D/S notation, shown on your admission stamp
> or paper Form I-94 is the official record of your authorized length of
> stay in the United States. You cannot use the visa expiration date in
> determining or referring to your permitted length of stay in the
> United States.

https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date.html

Comment: +1 However that said people entering on the dying days of their visa get extra scrutiny.

Comment: Nothing here suggests that this is a visitor visa.  If it is not, then of course the part of this answer about being a genuine visitor does not apply.

Comment: @phoog true, but ill leave it in incase for now

Comment: Anyway the rest of the answer is perfectly applicable to any nonimmigrant.